# Moveit2 Octomap Setup

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot figure out how to get an octomap to show up in moveit2. I can pass a sensors_3d.yaml as parameters to the move_group and without a transform from the camera to the robot and the move group will come up with errors saying there is no transform link between the two. No octomap displays in rviz2 however and the planning scene topics does not have anything publishing.
I am unable to run the octomap server manually so far.

move group output when parameters for sensor passed to move group without transform

```
    [move_group-4] [WARN] [1634575155.847092398] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Unable to transform object from frame 'camera_link' to planning frame'base_link' (Could not find a connection between 'base_link' and 'camera_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.)
```

occupany node output when launch from file as node after move_group

```
    [moveit_ros_occupancy_map_server-6] [WARN] [1634576010.368767799] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
    [moveit_ros_occupancy_map_server-6] [WARN] [1634576010.368801697] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor]: No target frame specified for Octomap. No transforms will be applied to received data.
    [moveit_ros_occupancy_map_server-6] [ERROR] [1634576010.368816836] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
    [moveit_ros_occupancy_map_server-6] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
    [moveit_ros_occupancy_map_server-6]   what():  Node has already been added to an executor.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388917/moveit2-octomap-setup/) by [seandburke99](https://answers.ros.org/users/59327/seandburke99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2021-10-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This guy asked the same question then found the result. [MoveIt!2 add Pointcloud2 to OccupancyMapMonitor](https://answers.ros.org/question/389233/moveit2-add-pointcloud2-to-occupancymapmonitor/)

---

Originally posted by [seandburke99](https://answers.ros.org/users/59327/seandburke99/) with karma: 38 on 2021-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0